# Spring data JPA findBy returns null

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using a spring data JPA and getting a weird issue.
Method findBY.. and findOne() returns null value whereas findAll() returns all the record present in the database.

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
private String name;
@Id 
private String nino;
private Integer employerId;
private Integer employmentLevel;
```

**Repository class**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends  JpaRepository<Person, String>{

    Person findByNino(String nino);
}
```

**Service class**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    private Person fetchPerson(String nino)
    {
        return personRepository.findByNino(nino);
    }
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: you are searching for the correct Nino? have you tried debugging to see if the string is what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the string value is coming correct in the method call. I have debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue which I figured out was :

I was hitting the service http://localhost:8080/getPerson?nino= "AB"&id=1 from the postman.

Double quotes were the issue. It should be http://localhost:8080/getPerson?nino= AB&id=1

Answer (score 1):

Your method should work, please check your nino value. Just for make sure and testing purpose, use the alternative method -

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.nino = :nino")
Person findByNino(@Param("nino") String nino);
```

Comment: I have used this query to test. Still the result is null.

This is the console output:

select person0_.nino as nino1_0_, person0_.employer_id as employer2_0_, person0_.employment_level as employme3_0_, person0_.name as name4_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.nino=?

Comment: Can you share the requested data and the data from DB table?